# Python Failed to Verify any CRLs for SSL/TLS connections

Tags: python, ssl

In Python 3.4, a `verify_flags` that can be used to check if a certificate was revoked against CRL, by set it to `VERIFY_CRL_CHECK_LEAF` or `VERIFY_CRL_CHECK_CHAIN`.

I wrote a simple program for testing. But on my systems, this script failed to verify ANY connections even if it's perfectly valid.

```
import ssl
import socket

def tlscheck(domain, port):
        addr = domain

        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.options &= ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
        ctx.verify_flags = ssl.VERIFY_CRL_CHECK_LEAF

        ctx.check_hostname = True

        #ctx.load_default_certs()
        #ctx.set_default_verify_paths()
        #ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt")

        sock = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=addr)
        sock.connect((addr, port))

        import pprint
        print("TLS Ceritificate:")
        pprint.pprint(sock.getpeercert())
        print("TLS Version:", sock.version())
        print("TLS Cipher:", sock.cipher()[0])
        exit()

tlscheck("stackoverflow.com", 443)
```

My code always quits with `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)`.

First I suspected that the certificate database was not loaded properly. But after I tried `load_default_certs()`, `set_default_verify_paths()`, `load_verify_locations(cafile="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt")`, and none of them worked.

Also, `ctx.options &= ssl.CERT_REQUIRED` works as expected, it can tell if a certificate chain is trusted or not. But not for CRLs... It also indicates that my CAs are correct.

I know "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" contains valid CAs. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check against CRL you have to manually download the CRL and put them in the right place so that the underlying OpenSSL library will find it. There is no automatic downloading of CRL and specifying the place where to look for the CRL is not intuitive either. What you can do:

- get the CRL distribution points from the certificate. For stackoverflow.com one is http://crl3.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g5.crl
- download the current CRL from there
- convert it from the DER format to PEM format, because this is what is expected in the next step: 
  `openssl crl -inform der -in sha2-ha-server-g5.crl  > sha2-ha-server-g5.crl.pem`
- add the location to the verify_locations:
  `ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile="./sha2-ha-server-g5.crl.pem")`

This way you can verify the certificate against the CRL.

Comment: One doesn't have to save the file to disk nor convert it manually since `load_verify_locations()` accepts a parameter called `cadata`, where a binary bytestring can be passed in both DER or PEM  format.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Anyway, the `ssl` module in Python has a terrible design, it doesn't provide any APIs to allow one to check if a known certificate is revoked! That means I simply cannot check the CRLs **after** the connection is created, but a two-pass process is needed: make a connection to get the CRL, and make another connection to communicate...Anyhow, it was written in an era where proper encryption was ignored...

Comment: @比尔盖子: that's actually the design of the underlying openssl library. Apart from that you usually don't want to load often huge CRL files to check for revocation. The way to go is instead OCSP. But it looks like  python does not support an easy way to do OCSP checks, similar to various other programming languages.

Comment: Yes, that's **exactly** where the problem is. Pre-Snowden cryptography stdlibs in various languages suffer from those issues.